# How to convert String to Date to String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have this type of string, "2019-03-22", and want to convert it to this string, "March 22, 2019", in Swift.

It looks simple and I tried a few different ways. But I haven't figured it out yet.

The best code I have is this:

```
let originalDate = "2019-03-22"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from:originalDate)!
print(newDate)
```

But I get this error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert *`string(from: string`* which is not possible.

You have first to convert the string to **date** with the format `yyyy-MM-dd` and then change the format and convert it back to string.

```
let dateString = "2019-03-22"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from:date)
print(newDate)
```

Comment: Ahh I had to format it twice! Thank you this worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the provided date string.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Now read the date string.

```
let aDate = dateFormatter.date(from: originalDate)
```

And then you provide the new format

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
let newDateString = dateFormat.string(from: aDate)
```

Now the output is:

> March 22, 2019

FullCode:

```
let originalDate = "2019-03-22"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let aDate = dateFormatter.date(from: originalDate)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: aDate)
print(newDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am already using the following method in my project :

```
func dateFormat(_ originalDate: String) -> String{
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
     dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
     let date = dateFormatter.date(from: originalDate)
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
     let valueDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
     return valueDate
}
```

You can utilize the method like this :

```
dateFormat("2019-03-22") // March 22, 2019
```

Comment: As `originalDate` is non-optional it cannot be `nil`. The check is pointless

Comment: Actually it’s exactly the same as my answer except it’s wrapped in a function and it declares two completely unnecessary variables.

Comment: Actually I have used this method in my code, so it becomes easy to use when wrapped in a function. Just need to pass the parameter while calling the function and it can be used anywhere in the project.